# AVPlayer and iPod asset URLs

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

Does ANYONE know if AVPlayer supports playing AVURLAssets init'd with iPod asset URLs (MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL). Docs imply yes bit can't get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Be sure to set your audio category to one that allows iPod mixing. Like Ambient.